# Excel - Conditional Formatting not detecting String with html tags at the beginning

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

Good day, I'm running this conditional formatting code in excel to find duplicate value. Row with same value will be highlighted with Red in column 1

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1,$D:$D,$D1,$E:$E,$E1)>1
```

and it is correct with below result

[image: Correct]

But, with data that consist html tag, it is not functioning very well. Refer image below. Row 8 should be not indicate as duplicate as the value in column E is differ

[image: Row 8 should be not indicate as duplicate as the value in column E is differ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to avoid `COUNTIFS`, try this version

`=AND($A1<>"",SUM(0+($A$1:$A$100&"-"&$B$1:$B$100&"-"&$C$1:$C$100&"-"&D$1:$D$100&"-"&$E$1:$E$100=$A1&"-"&$B1&"-"&$C1&"-"&$D1&"-"&$E1))>1)`

I recommend a restricted range for efficiency - I used 100 rows, expand as required

Comment: Wow!..Thanks a lot. It functioning like as i want.. Gracias

Comment: Hi..I'm encounter another issue which is when i want to add the formula using VBA, it does not auto detect like before. Can you please assist?
Code: With Range("$A:$A").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="your given code")

Comment: @Azlan Sorry, I don’t know what would cause that - did you double up the quotes in the formula?

Comment: Yes. I have double up the quotes in the formula. But I found that I need to save and close and reopen back then the formula works. I also found that the formula works when I click apply in the condtional formula box.

Comment: In conditional formatting there's no distinction between formulas that require "array entry" and those that don't, but I wonder if that's an issue - try replacing 'SUM' with 'SUMPRODUCT'

Comment: still not working..humm maybe I need to figured out another way.